# Mongodb + Node.js - Stream distinct query results

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am using the mongodb driver with Node.js.
I have a collection with over 1 million documents and I would like to do something like the following:

```
var stream = collection.distinct('id',{month:"March"}).stream();
stream.on('data', function(data){console.log(data)})
```

This returns an error but I would like to do something similar.
I would only like to return unique 'id' values from my collection but I am running into memory errors when I try the standard method outlined in their documentation because of the number of results that would populate the returned array.

Is there any other way to get around this?

Any help would be great.

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using?  If you are using 2.6, then you can use an [`aggregate`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) query to get the distinct id's which will return a cursor rather than a single document.  So, you aren't bound by the max BSON document size (16 MB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following aggregation:

```
db.collection.aggregate({$group:{_id:"$id"}})
```

If you are on the latest version (2.6.0), you will get a cursor back you can iterate over.

Comment: If I was to use this, how would this be unique id values?

Comment: this groups by "id" value - normally you would use this to get sums or averages grouped by id - here you don't need another field so you only get unique id values.